# What determines the Abilities of a Contractor?

Tags: darker-than-black

What determines the abilities of a Contractor?  In the anime two contractors have the same ability.  Both dealing having the powers of electricity.

So does this mean that there can many contractors with the same ability?

Comment: what two characters had electricity? As far as I can tell no two characters have same ability except hei and his sister. Hei is not an actual contractor (bai used her power to give him her powers), and their abilities not actually electricity but molecular manipulation. http://darkerthanblack.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Abilities

Comment: I personally believe the powers are more like One Piece (Ace and Akainu) in the sense two people may display similar abilities but the core nature is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be randomized as to what kind of power you get. If you could "pick" your power, every Contractor would logically choose things like shooting giant laser beams. Same with the remuneration, although it sometimes seems to be things that the Contractor hates, like the woman who hates smoking who had to eat cigarretes.

Comment: That women didn't hate smoking.  It was just that she quit during pregnancy.  Then her baby dies by choking on cigarettes.  And thats why the remuneration was eating cigarettes.